# How to make error bars for a 3D Bar graph?

Tags: python, graph, 3d

I'm new to coding and am trying to Frankenstein a graph for a research presentation. I would like to add an error bar to each bar value. Any help would be really appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```py
import numpy as np
#from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

result=[['29', '16', '15', '9', '20','6'],
        ['61', '27', '29', '29', '27','13'],
        ['77', '48', '51', '50', '50','8'],
        ['147', '105', '107','103', '103','41'],
        ['146', '117', '111', '105', '108','73']]

result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)
colors = ['r','b','g','y','b','p']
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=250)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.set_xlabel('Point in Process', labelpad=10)
ax1.set_ylabel('W% Solids', labelpad=10)
ax1.set_zlabel('Thickness nm')
xlabels = np.array(['PED', 'DEV', 'HR1','HR2', 'HR3', 'Trigger'])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(['1','2','3','4','5'])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos=result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx=0.5
dy=0.5
dz=zpos

ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx/2.)
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)

ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy/2.)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])
colors = cm.rainbow(values)
ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz*0, dx, dy, dz, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image: my bar graph]